# invert colormap in scilab

Tags: scilab, colormap

Is there anyway we can invert colormaps in scilab? When I use the hotcolormap, the color map is from red to yellow. Red for smaller values and yellow for higher values. I wanted to make a plot with yellow for smaller values and red for higher values.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy:

```
cmap=hotcolormap(128);// a 128 by 3 array
//invert the cmap rows and set the current figure colormap
set(gcf(),"color_map",cmap($:-1:1))
```

Any other change on the cmap rows can be done assuming the cmap elements values are between 0 and 1

Comment: There is a mistake here. You have reorder only the lines, not the whole ``cmap`` matrix. Therefore, inside ``set()``, you should use ``cmap($:-1:1,:)`` instead.